# Go to the Desktop on my Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

I really want to go to my desktop on my Mac to find files. I'm new to the Mac, so I have been minimizing other windows to get there.

What's the secret key combo?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [ask] and try to search for a solution before asking a question. This should have been quite easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F11</kbd>. It may be <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> if you have `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` unchecked under `System Preferences` → `Keyboard` → `Keyboard`.

Additionally you could check your shortcuts on `System Preferences` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 0):

try with F11 or Command-F3, they both show you the desktop